# popToRootViewControllerAnimated is not working with tabbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have this problem with popToRootViewControllerAnimated which I could not find a solution for, not even amongst all the questions in this site.

Basically, I have a main tabbar, with a UIViewController in each tab. On one of the tabs, I have a button to move to the next screen (say B). In the B viewcontroller, I have another button to go to the next view controller, say C. What I am trying to accomplish is to go back to A from C with one click. Thats my code:

To get from A to B, I do this:

```
ExerciseNextScreen *exerciseNextScreen = [[ExerciseNextScreen alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:exerciseNextScreen animated:YES];
```

Then from B to C, I do this:

```
 ScreenOneExercise *screenOneExercise = [[ScreenOneExercise alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *screenOneExerciseNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:screenOneExercise];
[self presentModalViewController:screenOneExerciseNav animated:YES];
```

Now, in C, I do that while trying to get back to A:

```
- (IBAction)cancelView:(id)sender
{
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

When getting into the cancelView method, nothing happens. I checked self.navigationController right before this call, and it't not nil.

Any ideas how can I go back to the A view controller? I tried everything in this forum, but with no avail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the method `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` does not work with modal views. You need to call the method `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` first to dismiss all your modal views. I guess you need to call the method on your controller A to dismiss all modal views at once.

Cheers,
anka

Comment: how do I do that? I am not sure I am following...how can I call dismissModalViewControllerAnimated on A from C?

Comment: You could use the `parentViewController` property to access your controller A from C.